# How can I make a time picker in angular like ios?

Tags: angular, user-interface, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have to implement a time picker in angular with the format or look of those of ios in angular and i dont know where to start!

For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNCRv.png

Or something like: https://stackblitz.com/github/IgniteUI/igniteui-live-editing-samples/tree/master/angular-demos/scheduling/timepicker-sample-5

Comment: Can you share what you tried already and how that did not work?

Comment: What I have done has been to create a div with overflow with several <a> tags representing the numbers, let's say that of 24 numbers, only 5 are displayed at the same time because of the overflow and to see the others I scroll up or down and there it is the problem, how to identify of the 5 that are present the number that is in the middle.

I hope I have answered your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> how to identify of the 5 that are present the number that is in the middle?

You can compute the current position based on the `window:scroll` event as follows:

```
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  handleHHScroll(event) {
    this.hhValue = this.getValueByPosition(event.target.scrollTop, 'hh');
    this.hhScroll$.next(this.hhValue);
  }

  getValueByPosition(y, type) {
    let arr = type === 'hh' ? this.hhArray : this.mmArray;
    let index = Math.floor((y+17)/33);
    if(index < 0) index = 0;
    if(index >= arr.length) index = arr.length -1;
    return arr[index];
  }
```

Based on the current position you can compute the before and after part and render it on the UI

Theres already an existing implementation at https://github.com/asdftu/ng-time-picker, see if that helps.